# How do Java Module directives impact reflection access into a module?

Tags: java, reflection, java-9, java-module, module-info

According to https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html, the Java Module system introduces the following directives:

- exports, exports ... to
- uses
- provides ... with
- open, opens, opens ... to

What (if any) impact does each directive have on an external module accessing internal members using reflection?

For example, does `exports <package>` allow external modules to access all `public`, `protected`, `private` members of the exported package using reflection? What about the other directives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would simply quote the [#JLS7.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7) here (formatted and categorized by me):

> Distinct from access at compile time and access at runtime, the Java
>   SE Platform provides reflective access via the Core Reflection API
>   [(§1.4)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-1.html#jls-1.4).

More towards your question categorising as Normal module(`module foo`) and Open module (`open module bar`):

#### Normal Module

> A **normal module** grants reflective *access to types in only
>   those packages which are explicitly exported or explicitly opened* (or
>   both).

- the module's exported packages (`exports com.example.foo.bar`)

  > For *code outside a normal module*, the reflective access granted to
  >   types in the module's exported (and not opened) packages is
  >   specifically to the `public` and `protected` ty*p*es in those packages, and
  >   the `public` and `protected` *members* of those types.
- the module's opened packages (`opens com.example.foo.internal to com.example.bar`)

  > The reflective access
  >   granted to types in the module's opened packages (whether exported or
  >   not) is to *all types in those packages, and all members of those
  >   types*.
  >
  > *No reflective access is granted to types, or their members, in
  >   packages which are not exported or opened*.
- within a module

  > The code *inside the module*
  >   enjoys reflective access to all types, and *all their members, in all
  >   packages in the module*.

#### Open Module

> An **open module** grants reflective access *to types in all its
>   packages, as if all packages had been opened*.

- the module's opened packages

  > For code *outside an open module*, the reflective access granted to
  >   types in the module's opened packages (that is, all packages in the
  >   module) is *to all types in those packages, and all members of those
  >   types*.
- within a module

  > Code *inside the module* enjoys reflective access *to all types,
  >   and all their members, in all packages in the module*.

Comment: Apart from these `uses` pertains more towards consuming a Service implementation and `provides` over provisioning an implementation.

Comment: Excellent answer. There is just one section I don't understand. For `opens X to Y` why does the documentation say `the code inside the module enjoys reflective access to [...] all packages in the module`. Isn't access limited to package `X`?

Comment: @Gili When written as `module A { opens X to B; }` ... Within a module, using reflection, all package's types/member is accessible across. But a `module B {requires A;}` only gets to access all the types/members of `package X`.