# How to replace VM Arguments with module-info.java file

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, runtime-error, jvm-arguments

I have just started a new project based on `AdoptOpenJDK 11` and `OpenJavaFX 11`.

Before during my development, I used VM Arguments which was not always practical when you pass the project to someone else.

So I started to replace my VM Arguments with the `module-info.java` file.

VM Arguments before:

```
--module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} –add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml 

--add-opens
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.runtime=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED
```

`module-info.java` file now:

```
module hellofx {

requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires transitive javafx.graphics;

opens org.openjfx to javafx.fxml;
exports org.openjfx;

}
```

This is where I have a problem, I managed to replace the tag `--module path` but I can not find a solution for tags `--add-open`.

Can someone help me?

**Edit 12/09:**

Now I have a new error with this two lines in the `module-info.java`

`Duplicate requires entry: javafx.fxml`

How I can solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Java Module directives impact reflection access into a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927375/how-do-java-module-directives-impact-reflection-access-into-a-module)

Comment: I suppose “I managed to replace the tag `--module path`” actually means “I managed to replace `–add-modules`” and that’s all you can achieve. You can not declare in your module that others open towards you. That would defeat the entire modularization. The fix is to rewrite your application to not rely on interna of other modules.

Comment: Perhaps my answer [on defining module info for a JavaFX project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57897944/1155209) might help you.

Comment: You should open *your* application’s root package to ‘javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml;‘ not ‘org.openjfx’.

Comment: If you are still stuck, when you run the modularized app, you will get a stack trace, Edit the question to add it.

Comment: @jewelsea I have a new error now, check my edits. Thanks

Comment: The error message seems obvious, you have a duplicate `requires` entry for `javafx.fxml` in your `module-info.java` file, so you need to remove one of the duplicates.  I don't know what you're module-info.java file is, my guess is that it is different than whatever you have in your question.

Comment: @jewelsea No it's exactly the same I wrote, I could put a picture to show it. By cons in JavaFX, JAR files also contain modules files that could come from there.

Answer (score 2):

Option A Quick and clean :

Change

```
module hellofx {

requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires transitive javafx.graphics;

//wrong
opens org.openjfx to javafx.fxml;

//right
opens com.your.package to javafx.fxml, javafx.controls;

exports org.openjfx;

}
```

Option B (Because building a Jar with javaFX seems to be wierd)

You also can do this with Gradle (because you then can easily build your JavaFX jar without much of a Problem)

You should add the gradle fx Plugin, and define Compile arguments.

When you use Gradle you also don't need to download the openJavaFX library manually.

Here is how your Gradle file should look like

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins', name: 'javafx-gradle-plugin', version: '8.7.0'
        classpath 'org.openjfx:javafx:11'

    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
         maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }

    }
}

plugins {
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'application'
    // This is very Important!
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.12.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}



mainClassName="com.your.MainLauncher"



// Use this for the Runtime, to run with the required Modules

javafx {
    version = "11"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml','javafx.graphics']
}


sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDir "src/main/java"
    main.resources.srcDir "src/main/resources"
}

// Your dependecies
dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx', version: '11.0.2'
    // JAVA FX dependecy. Important!
    // Add your other dependecies


}

// to build the jar
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Main-Class': 'com.your.MainLauncher'
    )

  }
  from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

// to "include compile arguments " that replace your VM arguments
compileJava {
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics'
        ]
        println options.compilerArgs
    }

}
```

you can run this with gradle but also with eclipse. 
When you build the jar there are also no VM arguments required. I Hope this will help you.

This does also run out of your IDE(intelliJ / Eclipse) if you have Gradle Support plugins installed.

Comment: Hi, to use this, you need an internet connection?

Comment: @ValentinDubois-Pivot Yes you need internet, at least when you refresh your project or for the initial load of the Dependencies. Once downloaded Via Gradle there is no need for internet, except you want to update your dependencies.

Comment: This computer has no way to connect to the internet. It is dedicated to a rescritive use. So it can not work with this method?

Comment: @ValentinDubois-Pivot It can work, but in that case, you need to have the required Dependencies, already downloaded or stored somwhere: 
`implementation files('libs/your_jar.jar')` . You the PC you develop on has no internet or the Machine the code should be deployed has no internet ?

Comment: The Pc has no connection so I can download and store the required dependencies.